# extrude svg house plan

Tags: faces, extrude, svg

I am a beginner in using blender. I imported a svg file in blender. It is a house plan and I would like to extrude the different walls. I tried to take quick suggestions from different manuals but it seems almost impossible to transform each wall in face and to extrude it.
Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you add an image or two of your blender scene and describe what you have tried? We don't know how your imported SVG file looks like. Is your imported house plan a lot of curves or a mesh? How do you want to transform it? Why exactly is it impossible to transform and extrude it? What do you mean by "transform"?

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the meanwhile I discovered that it is impossible to extrude an image, I can use it just as a base.